# IIS 404 Custom Error not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

I'm working on IIS6, ASP.NET, VS2008. The web site uses a custom error handler to catch 404 errors and serve an alternate page. When presented with an url of the form:

**http://srv/crimson/articles/index**

Everything works perfectly. But an url of the form:

**http://srv/crimson/blog.aspx**

Where blog.aspx does not exist, fails with the following message:

Server Error in '/Crimson' Application. Description: HTTP 404...

When I try and debug, none of the breakpoints in my 404 handler are hit. So it appears that something is catching the request earlier. Where? And how to I get it to pass the request on to my handler?

**Edit**
Thanks to those who answered, but none of those ideas worked. I've decided to attack the problem another way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might wanna try this:

In IIS6:

- open "properties" for your website
- go to "home directory" tab
- click on "configuration"
- look for the extension ".aspx"
- click on "edit"
- check the checkbox which says "verify that file exists"

*edit*

And what about this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(VS.80).aspx

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="sorry.htm" mode="On">  
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="NotFound.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

Since 'RemoteOnly' specifies that custom errors are shown only to the remote clients, and that ASP.NET errors are shown to the local host.

Answer (score 7):

hmm, Assaf is right, but to add to his answer I need to post some code.

Yes, Assaf does mean something else ASP.NET offers it's own error handling, configured through the [web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx). You can either manage this through the IIS Admin snap in, or directly in the web.config file.

Within the <system.web> element you should have:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="sorry.htm" mode="RemoteOnly">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="NotFound.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

You can configure a different page for each HTTP error code, or let the default redirect handle them all.

You'll find that you do indeed need to set these error pages up in **both** the IIS custom errors and the ASP.NET configuration, as otherwise you'll end up in this situation - some pages go to your 404, and others use a default that you've not customised.

You should also make sure that your custom 404 page actually returns a 404 header to ensure that search engines etc treat it correctly.

```
Response.StatusCode = 404;
Response.StatusDescription = "Not found";
```

Answer (score 2):

ASP.Net has a custom errors configuraiton of its own.

Go to the ASP.Net configuration of your virtual directory (web application) and right-click -> ASP.Net -> Edit Configuration -> Custom Errors.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I set a custom error in my virtual directory Right Click -> Properties -> Custom Errors. That is what should work but doesn't. If you mean something else, I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got a 500 so redirect for 404 is not triggered. You may focus on this 500 error at first.