# Modx error page won't display

Tags: iis, iis-7, modx

I've developed a site in modx but after migrating it to the live server if I enter a page that doesn't exist (eg http://mysite.com/index.php?id=5) I'm getting the default IIS error page rather than the page specified in Tools->Configuration->site->Error page

Any idea why this could be happening?

For the record I developed on Apache but am deploying to IIS.

Comment: Will it display the error page using the relevant id? ie if your error page is number 6 then open index.php?id=6 . The notes do say the error page has to be published and publically accessable. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes if I navigate directly to the error page it displays as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that IIS is over-riding the modX error page somehow.

I know on Apache I can fiddle with the .htaccess file to set ErrorDocument, but I don't know how IIS works.

Perhaps previous SO questions on "[custom 404 page on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615829/iis-404-custom-error-not-working-as-expected)" might give you some clues as to how your system is setup.

Comment: The thing I don't really get is that I'm not using url re-writing and the site is working eg. /index.php?id=3 displays fine, the error pages itself (index.php?id=39) displays fine. But if I enter a non-existent page such as index.php?id=654 I'm getting an IIS error page when index.php cleary exists as has been demonstrated.