# Custom http error pages for images?

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404, custom-errors

I know it's common for pages to redirect to a custom error page for 404 errors and such. But say somebody opens the url in their browser for an image that doesn't exist for example http://mysite.com/nothinghere.gif. This site returns a 404 error but it's not just the browser default, it's a custom 404. How do you configure an ASP.NET site on IIS7 to do this? the customerrors section in the web.config doesn't seem to apply to things like images, css, js, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`customErrors` section would apply to resources managed by ASP.NET. IIS7 has its own `httpErrors` section under webserver node. Of course, there is also UI to configure it. Anyway error handling behavior also changes based on you are running your ASP.NET application under classic mode or integrated mode. I will suggest that you read following articles to get hold of it.

http://www.braintrove.com/article/46 - this will tell you how to set up IIS7's own cutom error pages

Below explains IIS7 errors handling

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/267/how-to-use-http-detailed-errors-in-iis-70/
http://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/archive/2008/02/18/what-to-expect-from-iis7-custom-error-module.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Make your custom error page a script.

When its called you can either send a html response for a page missing or query the request to find out the image name and then send an image or redirect to an image.

try these links for issues with custom 404 errors
[IIS 404 Custom Error not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615829/iis-404-custom-error-not-working-as-expected)
http://forums.asp.net/p/1603843/4089618.aspx