# Faking Http Status Codes in IIS/.net for testing

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-codes

This is quite an odd question, but I am trying to test the Web.Config settings for custom errors e.g.:

```
  <customErrors mode="On"/>
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="500.html"/>  
    <error statusCode="500.13" redirect="500.13.html"/>        
  </customErrors>
```

Is there anyway I can create a page or intercept the request in the global.asax `Application_BeginRequest` method that can fake up a response to send to the browser i.e. setup a 500.13 HTTP error status which tells IIS to use the `500.13.html` page defined in the Web.Config.

Ideally, I'd like to do something like create a page that takes a query string value of the status code I want returned e.g. `FakeRequest.html?errorStatus=500.13` so that our testers can make sure the appropriate page is returned for the various errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rawErorStatus = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Get("errorStatus");

        int errorStatus;
        if (int.TryParse(rawErorStatus, out errorStatus))
        {
            throw new HttpException(errorStatus, "Error");
        }
    }
```

Found this at the following page: http://aspnetresources.com/articles/CustomErrorPages

Comment: That's the ticket! This seems to be doing the trick for me! Thanks Paul!

Answer (score 0):

This won't work for all but you can flesh it out... The cache setting is important otherwise the last code they try could be cached by the browser etc.

Create a basic page, e.g. "FakeError.aspx":

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<script runat="server" language="c#">

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.StatusCode = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["code"]);
    Response.End();
  }

</script>
</html>
```

Then hit it...

- http://example.com/FakeError.aspx?code=302
- http://example.com/FakeError.aspx?code=404
- Etc.

Like I said, not all will work but see how you go.

For status codes, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383887(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks Paul, unfortunately this isn't quite what I need. The response that comes back on the page load is correct, but it is not being intercepted by IIS to use the pages defined in the web.config. Thanks, Dan

Comment: interesting! This answer talks of configuring both IIS and ASP.NET level... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615829/iis-404-custom-error-not-working-as-expected/616467#616467

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for this, but this is already what I have done (mentioned in my question). The web.config is already setup to handle the error status pages, and I want to fake a request up so that IIS is forced to use the pages defined in the web.config for testing. Thanks again