# Faking Http Sub Status Codes in IIS/.net for testing

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-codes

Now this is tightly coupled to the question I raised and had [answered yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724998/faking-http-status-codes-in-iis-net-for-testing).

This question/answer works well for testing asp.net errors (such as straight for 500, 404, 502 etc errors) but when I have tried to test errors such as 500.13 - Web server is too busy, or 502.2 - Bad gateway, I can't work out how to do this.

I think there is a clear difference between error generated/handled by asp.net and those by IIS (IIS dealing with the sub status codes such as 500.13 etc.).

Has anyone any ideas on how to test these? I found to handle these sub status errors in the web.config you do so in the following way:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <clear/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/errorPages/404.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
  <error statusCode="500" path="/errorPages/500.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
  <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="13" path="/errorPages/500.13.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
  <error statusCode="502" subStatusCode="2" path="/errorPages/502.2.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
</httpErrors>
```

To recap, I simply want to be able to simulate/replicate an sub status error such as 500.13 or 502.2 in .net so that I can test IIS returns the correct page I have specified in the web.config.

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way would be to create a page in your app that returns the [status code you want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse_members%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

**Page_Load**
// HttpContext.Current.Response

```
Response.Clear();
if(Request.QueryString["code"] == null)
   Response.StatusCode = someDefault;
else
   Response.StatusCode = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["code"]);
```

You could receive a query string parameter so that it would be easier to automate.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer but this isn't what Im looking for. As noted in the question I want IIS to be intercepting/handling the request and respond with the correct page defined in the web.config. Changing Response.StatusCode just changes the response header code and doesn't get intercepted by IIS as it is too late in the life cycle by then